# Product image import through csv throws required sku error

Tags: product, import, image, csv, multiple

I`ve multiple images for single product and I`m trying to import it through csv  as shown below. [image]

when I`m importing this csv file it gives me required sku error. So am i missing something here or my csv is incorrect?

Comment: Are you using default import product method in magento?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the default import method in Magento.